# css colors not showing in dynamically created link

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

hi guys i am a bit lost with giving a dynamically created links it's respective css class in my JavaScript code i am adding rows to a grid view dynamically

here is the code:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Customers");
            var totalRows = $("#<%=gvCustomers.ClientID()%> tr").length;
            if (totalRows <= 1) {
                $('#gvCustomers tbody tr:first').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
            }
            var row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
            $.each(customers, function () {
                var customer = $(this);
                $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("fname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("mname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("lname").text());
                $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("qualifier").text());
                $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("alias").text());
                $("td", row).eq(5).html('<a class=1ref target=_blank href=ShowInformation.aspx?id=' + $(this).find("pid").text() + '><i class=icon-zoom-in icon-white></i>View</a>' + '&nbsp;' +
                 '<a class=2ref href=AddNew.aspx?pid=' + $(this).find("pid").text() + '&edit=1' + '><i class=icon-edit icon-white></i>Edit Info</a>' + '&nbsp;' + '<a class=2ref href=CreateSession.aspx?pid=' + $(this).find("pid").text() + '><i class=icon-edit icon-white></i>Edit MugShot</a>');
                $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            });
```

now on my jquery code

```
$("body").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
                $(this).find('.1ref').addClass('btn btn-primary');
                $(this).find('.2ref').addClass('btn btn-warning');

            });
```

now when i view it on my browser the outcome is that the supposed color of the created link is not showing this class 'btn btn-primary' would make the link color blue while this one 'btn btn-warning' should show the color orange

i am using twitter bootstrap

is there a mistake on my code or lackings if anything?

thank you

Comment: Why you are not wrapping attributes of dynamically created elements in quotes? Do it first. i.e. `<i class=icon-zoom-in icon-white></i>` will be rendered as `<i class="icon-zoom-in" icon-white></i>`. Thus your second class `icon-white` have no effect

Comment: i have tried single and double quotes but same result ironically this part <i class=icon-zoom-in icon-white></i> which is inside the link is showing the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You should use your code after `changing` or `clicking` on your `target element`, or when your `element` is `inserted` in `DOM` like,

```
$DOMNodeInserted=$('yourElement');
$DOMNodeInserte.find('.1ref').addClass('btn btn-primary');
$DOMNodeInserte.find('.2ref').addClass('btn btn-warning');
```

Also, `escape` by a `\` in `multiline strings` like,

```
$("td", row).eq(5).html('<a class=1ref target=_blank \
                      href=ShowInformation.aspx?id='+this).find("pid").text()+'\
                 ><i class=icon-zoom-in icon-white></i>View</a>'.....
```

**Updated,** if your `links` are created`after`page load`or after`button click` then you should add it like,

```
function addLinks(){
   //your code here
   $DOMNodeInserted=$('yourElement');
   $DOMNodeInserte.find('.1ref').addClass('btn btn-primary');
   $DOMNodeInserte.find('.2ref').addClass('btn btn-warning');
}
```

Call above `function` in `document.ready` and after your `button click` like,

```
$(function(){
   addLinks();
   $('#buttonId').on('click',function(){ 
       addLinks();
   });// buttonId is id of button which add links after you click
});
```

`$DOMNodeInserted=$('yourElement');`  `yourElement` is your `dynamically created element selector`

Comment: the links are created after the page load and also when i click a search button should i also insert the code on the button click?

Comment: $DOMNodeInserted=$('yourElement'); means the parent element?

Comment: should i give every dynamic link an id?before calling the addlinks function?

Comment: You can pass `class name` or `element` in `addLinks()`.

Comment: my codes loops until the final record is reach so the button click in my project calls my function to load records i tried you're code but the effect is the same